# Inner join two lists based on a child list

Tags: c#, list, linq, join

I have two lists of *different* types of custom objects, and I'm trying to perform an inner join where the join criteria is contained within a child list of the objects.

Here's an example of my objects:

```
public class Container
{
    public List<Reference> Refs;

    public Container(List<Reference> refs )
    {
        Refs = refs;
    }
}

public class Reference
{
    public int Id;

    public Reference(int id )
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

And here's an example the data I'm working with:

```
List<Container> containers = new List<Container>()
{
    new Container(new List<Reference>()
    {
        new Reference(1),
        new Reference(2),
        new Reference(3)
    }),

    new Container(new List<Reference>()
    {
        new Reference(4),
        new Reference(5),
        new Reference(6)
    })
};

List<Reference> references = new List<Reference>()
{
    new Reference(4),
    new Reference(5),
    new Reference(6)
};
```

I'm trying to select all the `Container`s in `List<Container>` which have a matching `Reference` in the `List<Reference>` based on `Reference.Id`. With this data, I expect only the second item in the `List<Container>` to be selected.

If it were valid syntax, I'd be looking to do something along the lines of:

```
var query = from c in containers
            join r in references on c.Refs.Contains( r.Id )
            select c;
```

How can this be done? Thanks

---

Sorry for the poor title. I'm struggling to put this scenario into a short group of words - please suggest an edit if you can think of something more suitable. Thanks

Comment: might i recommend using an inherited class for list<reference> that implements iequatable...then you can use sequence equals to check if a given list<reference> matches your list...see this for details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an inner join is not necessary here, you're better off without it:

```
containers.Where(c => c.Refs.Any(x => references.Any(e => x.Id == e.Id)));
```

or if you want the entire set of Id's to be equal then use `SequenceEqual`:

```
var sequence = references.Select(e => e.Id);
var result = containers.Where(c => c.Refs.Select(s => s.Id).SequenceEqual(sequence));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
containers.Where(c => c.Refs.Select(r => r.Id).Intersect(references.Select(r => r.Id)).Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
var query = from c in containers where c.Refs.SequenceEqual(references)
                select c;
```

No join is necessary.